# how to add more rows to a existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

The table `instructor` has several columns. I only want to add more values to column `name` and the values are derived from the table `student`. The condition is that only `name` of student with `tot_cred > 100` is chosen. My try is below but it return error. How I can solve the problem?

```
update instructor
set id = (select id from student where tot_cred > '100');
```

the error is that

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Can you please give us the exact error you're getting as well as the version of sql you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update instructor a set 
a.name = (
    select name from student 
    where id = a.id
    )
where exists (
    select '' from student
    where id = a.id
    and tot_cred > '100'
);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `INSERT` statement, not an `UPDATE` statement:

```
INSERT INTO instructor (id) SELECT id from student where tot_cred > 100;
```